# Least cumbersome way of populating form fields with php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've got a form and would like to populate it with mysql data IF such data exists.  But what I've come up with on my own seems very cumbersome and I wondered if there's any better way to do it:

```
echo "<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='firstname' size='40' value='";
if ($row1['firstname']) { echo $row1['firstname']; } else echo '';
echo "' /></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>... (etc)
```

Just wondered if this is a good way to do this or if there's a shorthand or "better" way.

Thank you for any suggestions or help!

Comment: Your if check is redundant, the output will be the same if it exists or not. If you want to prevent the PHP notice, you should use if `(isset($row1['firstname'])) { ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have done it in the past is to use mysql_fetch_assoc() to return an associative array in the top of my php document, then throughout the html of the form, insert

```
<?=$row['column'];?>
```

into the value attribute.

**EDIT:** Do NOT use `mysql_` functions. Both PDO and MySQLi have equivalent functions that should be used instead. Google them, use them.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for.  It's working fine and since I'm not posting to $_SELF I don't need the ISSET...if there's no value, it's blank.  Otherwise, it posts the value that's there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

End the php block before the HTML part `?>` Then write pure HTML and just insert PHP block into it

```
<tr><td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='firstname' size='40' 
value="<?php echo ($row1["firstname"])?($row1['firstname']):($row1['firstname']); ?>" /></td></tr>
```

I also edited it a bit to use the shorten it (no need to use if-else):

```
echo (isset($row1["firstname"]) || !empty($row1["firstname"]))?($row1['firstname']):('')
```

Which basically outputs firstname if it is set, or nothing if it is not